# Using crystal report 11 with sybase ASE 15.0.3

Tags: crystal-reports, ssrs-2008, sap-ase

I am using following tools.

1. Crystal Report 11
2. Sybase ASE 15.0.3

I want to creat a basic report, by pulling data from a sybase table and creating some graph. Can we use these tools to create a report?

I google alot but couldnt found any resonable answer.

I will be appricate if i could get link or reference to create connection and sample reporting tutorial.

Comment: - Hi, if you found my answer helpful, please upvote and accept it.  For more information on how to accept an answer, please see the page here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to create reports using Crystal Reports, and Sybase ASE.  As far as I know, Crystal Reports relies on ODBC, so as long as you can connect to the database via ODBC, you should be able to run reports.

You will probably need to get a copy of the Sybase ASE ODBC driver.  It's usually included on the client CD's as part of the ASE download.  If you no longer have access to the original installation software you may be able to download the SDK from SAP.

This link from SAP support talks about some of the different places that you may be able [to get access to the SDK, or ODBC software](http://scn.sap.com/thread/3360231).

SAP has a large number of tutorials available on the [SAP Community Network site for Crystal Reports, so that is probably the best place to start](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-8514).

There is also a step-by-step guide published by SAP/Sybase on using [Crystal Reports with ASE 15.7, which although they are newer versions the information may still be helpful](http://www.sybase.com/detail?id=1094752).